# BakerFramework outside the newsstand

Tags: ios

I want to develop app using baker framework, but I don't want to open my app in newsstand.
I want to open my app as regular app.
In baker framework demo I added property in Plist Application presents content in Newsstand equals to NO.
Now my app is open as regular app, but the problem is downloading issue is not working, could anyone help me out what i need to do for that.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot more about this than just changing the plist. The whole download infrastructure in the Baker framework is built around Newsstand. If you disable Newsstand, this stops working.